# minor improvement in freeing nodes in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, declaration, free

Look at this code that wants to free all the malloced nodes inside a linked list in C:

```
    ptr = list;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        node *next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
```

The reasoning is that, we need a temporary variable next to store the pointer to the next node before freeing the current node.

Do you see that `node *next = ptr->next;` is inside the loop? So that every time the loop runs, there is a new temporary node created to store the pointer to the next node. Is it better if we create the variable node outside the loop and inside the loop we just reassign it?

Like this:

```
    ptr = list;
    node *next = NULL;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
```

Would it be more efficient?

Comment: "So that every time the loop runs, there is a new temporary node created " - that isn't true. There is no temporary node created. A temporary node *pointer* is accosted on the stack, and as a remedial scalar, isn't even with the worry about the silicon it is printed on.  I would be *shocked* if these two loops didn't optimize to identical code by any compiler worth its salt. That said, a common C preference is variable locality (keep it tight), and most C engineers would likely prefer the first approach. Btw probability is high that even `ptr` is redundant, and using `list` would be fine.

Comment: Even if you *did* create a temporary (copying the entire node) any decent compiler would allocate the space required for storing the copy just once (on stack) in *both* variants...

Comment: In C you need to care for much less anyway. C++ might be a different matter as you possibly need to account for constructors/destructors.

Comment: There is a downside to moving the declaration out of the loop - it increases the scope of the variable `node *next`.  That makes it somewhat more bug-prone.  That's not a problem in a trivial example like this, but in complex code doing everything possible to reduce the chances of introducing bugs can be important.  Limiting the scope of variables reduces the complexity of the code, and simpler code is easier to write and maintain while also being less bug-prone.

Comment: @Aconcagua Don't forget the *copy* constructors that will be called for the version with the declaration outside of the loop.  And then there's the problem of ensuring nothing's leaked when that copy constructor overwrites the values from the previous iteration....  I hate C++.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Copy constructor will be called anyway (unless you construct the element within the loop and profit from copy-elision): `for(...) { auto a = someExistingObject; }`

Comment: @Aconcagua I did assume that would be the case.  Hidden complexities like that are, umm, fun.  Yeah, fun.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

> there is a new temporary node created to store the pointer to the next node

No, there's a new temporary node *pointer* created.

Both versions will likely be optimized into exactly the same assembler code which can be seen in this [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zd4cz6hTb) where [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) produces two identical functions and [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) too.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two snippets is negligible. Both snippets have the same time complexity, which is `O(n)`, where n is the number of nodes in the linked list. They iterate through the linked list once, freeing each node. The additional step of initializing the `next` pointer in the 2nd code does not significantly impact performance.

Comment: The "additional" step of initializing the `next` pointer in the second code (technically an assignment, not an initialization) is matched with the in-declaration initialization of the `next` pointer in the first code.  The difference is rather the per-iteration *allocation* of `next` in the first example, vs. the once-for all allocation in the second.  If that were a dynamic allocation then it might indeed be something to worry about, but it is instead an automatic one, and the key point here is that automatic allocations are essentially free in most C implementations.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it better if we create the variable node outside the loop and inside the loop we just reassign it?

Trust your compiler to emit efficient code for such trivial optimizations - otherwise get a better compiler.  Code for clarity.

Save your valuable coding time for significant improvements.
[Is premature optimization really the root of all evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

Answer (score 2):

The proposed optimisation does not change anything: a local variable is used to store the `next` pointer, whether its scope is local to the loop body or not does not make a difference. The compiler, with optimisations enabled, will analyse the use of the `next` variable and generate similar if not identical code for both approaches.

The first one offers multiple benefits:

- `next` is defined with the smallest scope, making it easier for the next programmer to analyse at a glance its limited use.
- initializing `next` before the loop is an extra useless step, which will probably be eliminated by the compiler, but the next programmer way wonder if `next` is used after the loop and needs initializing.
- the first code snippet is a classic idiom.  Using classic idioms reduces the mental load for code reviewing and proofing.

If this loop happens to be a bottleneck, which you should test for before attempting optimisations, you should probably investigate if a linked list is the best data structure for your purpose and if so, you could use alternate ways to allocate nodes if you can free them all at once: allocating nodes from pre-allocated arrays is an efficient way to increase cache efficiency and allocation/deallocation performance.

Note that the `list` pointer will have an invalid value after the loop, unless the list was empty. You should set it to `NULL` explicitly or use it directly in the loop:

```
    while (list != NULL) {
        node *next = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
```

Comment: if we use the `list` instead of the `ptr`, we would lose the beginning of the list right?

Ah no we are going to free the list anyway, right?

Comment: @DrLinhChiNguyen: the list is freed completely, it makes no sense to keep a pointer to its original head node that was freed :)

Comment: @DrLinhChiNguyen Apart from: Code like that usually should be packed into its own function `void deleteList(node* list);` – and in that case `list` already *is* a copy of the pointer. In either case there's a dangling pointer left, be it `list` directly or – if function – the pointer passed to, which needs to be considered by the code still using it afterwards (-> setting to `NULL`, but considering potentially existing copies of, too!).

Answer (score -1):

> Do you see that node *next = ptr->next;  is inside the loop? So that
> every time the loop runs, there is a new temporary node created to
> store the pointer to the next node.

You are wrong. If you include a statement with a call of `printf` inside the for loop as shown here

```
ptr = list;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
  node *next = ptr->next;
  printf( "&next = %p\n", ( void * )&next );
  free(ptr);
  ptr = next;
}
```

You will see that the same address for the variable `next` is outputted in each iteration of the for loop. The variable is created in each iteration of the loop formally from the point of view of the abstract mashine. Actually on the physical level in this line

```
  node *next = ptr->next;
```

there is used the same assignemnt as in the second code snippet

```
next = ptr->next;
```

where the variable is declared before the for loop.

So on the generated code level there is no difference.

However from the point of view of writing programs you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

Also the introduced variable `ptr` is redundnt. After the for loop the pointer `list` will be a dangling pointer. So you will need to set it to `NULL` after the for loop. Instead you could just write

```
while ( list != NULL )
{
  node *next = list->next;
  free( list );
  list = next;
}
```

As you see there is no redundant variables and the pointer `list`  after the for loop will be equal to `NULL`.